# Could not access web page hosted by XAMPP after upgrade to win 10

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I have XAMPP working and host a web sit on my PC, it worked fine with Win8. But after upgrading to Win10, I could not access my web page from other PC, but from local PC it works fine(I use port 4000 so that avoiding system using port 80). XAMPP starts up and works properly. It looks like permission or service been denied, however I could not find why. Please help!

Comment: 1) Are they in the same ip range? 2) Did you check firewall rules? Personally I think you get a totally different ip, like `192.168.1.42` and `192.168.5.17`

Comment: @Thomas they are in same sub network, ip addresses used are 192.168.0.17 and 192.168.0.19 and I did not do any firewall change :(

Comment: Maybe windows 10 has other default firewall settings compared to windows 8!

Comment: @Thomas That's what I am asking, I do not know how to compare, I do not have win 8 here any more

Comment: You do not need it: just turn your firewall off to test this theory. If it checks out add a rule for that port to be open for TCP traffic.

Comment: @BingLan So just disable firewall for a few minutes and check if the server is working. Or simple solution would be to make a backup and reinstall xampp

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, your suggestion is right, it's firewall rule :(